# Editing files with netbeans without setting up project

Tags: netbeans

Is there a way to use netbeans as a simple text editor, without setting up a project?

I am interested in using netbeans features as a text editor, especially for making quick changes on remote servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can use it as a text editor. Just Open Netbeans and select `File > Open File` and select the file to open from the file chooser dialog. Make changes and click `Save`.

If you want to edit files on network locations, again do `File > Open File` and paste the location of your remote file.

Comment: Thanks! This really was a silly question... For some reason I remembered from so many years ago, that I tried it and couldn't make it happen.

Comment: @Skarlinski It opens, but you need to have it in a project to run it (preview in browser), which is annoying if you want to work on random html files that are not part of a site structure.